# ESB Mule 3.8.1 CE HTTP request thrown doSelect Error

Tags: mule, httprequest, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, grizzly

I have Anypoint 6.2.5
Mule 3.8.1 CE
When I am trying to send json to Magento2 Api.
Im using http request like that:

```
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/products/attributes" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
<http:request-builder>
<http:header headerName="Authorization" value="Bearer xxxx"/>
<http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
</http:request-builder>
</http:request>
```

Response Timeout is set to 10s
I got an error :

```
cze 28, 2017 8:48:03 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner doSelect
SEVERE: doSelect exception
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.HttpTransactionContext.getAsyncHandler()Lcom/ning/http/client/AsyncHandler; from class org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy
at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.getWorkManager(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:119)
at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.getThreadPoolFor(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:90)
at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:69)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:415)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:384)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:348)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:279)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

ERROR 2017-06-28 08:48:10,554 [[magento].readAttributeMessagesFromQueueFlow.stage1.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Error sending HTTP request.
Payload               : {"attribute":{"is_visible":true,"attribute_code":"ts_size","frontend_input":"select","default_frontend_label":"ts_size","options":[{"label":"36","value":"36","sort_order":0,"is_default":true,"store_labels":[{"label":"36","store_id":0}]},{"label":"S","value":"S","sort_order":0,"is_default":true,"store_labels":[{"label":"S","store_id":0}]},{"label":"XS","value":"XS","sort_order":0,"is_default":true,"store_labels":[{"label":"XS","store_id":0}]},{"label":"XL","value":"XL","sort_order":0,"is_default":true,"store_labels":[{"label":"XL","store_id":0}]},{"label":"L","value":"L","sort_order":0,"is_default":true,"store_labels":[{"label":"L","store_id":0}]},{"label":"M","value":"M","sort_order":0,"is_default":true,"store_labels":[{"label":"M","store_id":0}]},{"label":"ONE SIZE","value":"ONE SIZE","sort_order":0,"is_default":true,"store_labels":[{"label":"ONE SIZE","store_id":0}]},{"label":"34","value":"34","sort_order":0,"is_default":true,"store_labels":[{"label":"34","store_id":0}]},{"label":"40","value":"40","sort_order":0,"is_default":true,"store_labels":[{"label":"40","store_id":0}]},{"label":"42","value":"42","sort_order":0,"is_default":true,"store_labels":[{"label":"42","store_id":0}]},{"label":"38","value":"38","sort_order":0,"is_default":true,"store_labels":[{"label":"38","store_id":0}]}],"frontend_labels":[{"label":"ts_size","store_id":0}]}}
Payload Type          : [B
Element               : /readAttributeMessagesFromQueueFlow/processors/2 @ magento:Attributes.xml:24 (HTTP)
Element XML           : <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/products/attributes" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
                        <http:request-builder>
                        <http:header headerName="Authorization" value="Bearer 3vh5yv803usi8ik2ix695ukweu2j8nnq"></http:header>
                        <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="application/json"></http:header>
                        </http:request-builder>
                        </http:request>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout exceeded
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.timeout(GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.java:433)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider$3.onTimeout(GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.IdleTimeoutFilter$DefaultWorker.doWork(IdleTimeoutFilter.java:401)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.IdleTimeoutFilter$DefaultWorker.doWork(IdleTimeoutFilter.java:380)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.DelayedExecutor$DelayedRunnable.run(DelayedExecutor.java:158)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I dont really know how can I fix it.
I am sure that sending request works - new attribute in Magento was created correctly but error shown up and flow is stopped.
Some more details:

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown  
java.version=1.8.0_131  
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation  
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=pl_PL  
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64
```

It works without problems and without errors on my friends Pc. Am I missing some packages on my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved issue.

You need to remove a jar called async-http-client from you CE Runtime located at /lib/user folder.

Inside your AnyPointStudio installation locate you CE Runtime. It's something like this:

"../Eclipse/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.8.1_6.0.0.201612271237/mule/lib/user"

Located and delete the mentioned jar file, restart your AnyPointStudio and will be fine.

For Standalone Runtime just download the latest version from github and use maven to build it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **bug** already raised `MULE-8989` at https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8989 which is fixed in Mule runtime 3.8.2 https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-3.8.2-release-notes
Try upgrading our mule runtime

For more ref:- https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/58664/severe-doselect-exception.html

Comment: I found that. But following steps on https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/6/adding-community-runtime - the newest version of Mule Runetime is 3.8.1 only… In this website: https://developer.mulesoft.com/download-mule-esb-runtime version 3.8.2 of CE are not exist also. Am I miss something?